# Instagram API -Get the userId

Tags: instagram-api

We had integrated instagram api (with {userId}/media/recent) to get media feeds based on userId. It was working fine until June 1 2016 . Now on how do I get userId for new instagram pages which we need to include as with the new release of instagram it seems difficult. This is the error messsage we get from a site from where we used to get instagram userId.
"This service is no longer available as of 01. June, due to changes in Instagram's API rules" from http://www.otzberg.net/iguserid/

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 13):

Definitely not the most elegant way, but without involving a running browser or an approved application, is to use the (undocumented?) search API:

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query={username}
```

This returns matching users (as count is set to 0 it should not return more than one user).

After validating the results (checking if `user` includes one item), you can get the userid e.g. in javascript with

```
response.users[0].user.pk
```

where `response` is an object with the parsed response.

Comment: Thats not the userId of Instagram user.

Answer (score 10):

The mentioned website otzberg.net/iguserid is my personal site and I shut it down, based on the API announcement, which was correctly mentioned by Daniel Storm. The type of tool would never be approved by Instagram. However there are a few easy steps to get your Instagram User-ID, use Google Chrome and the Developer Tools (F12 or ⌥ + ⌘ + i)

In the console view of the profile page (e.g. https://www.instagram.com/lufthansa/) type:

```
    window._sharedData.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].user.id
```

Here a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The JSON object has changed. If OP's doesn't work, try this: `window._sharedData.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql.user.id`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this website - http://www.instaid.co.uk

Or you can do the following replacing {username} with your Instagram username

https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1

Or you can login to your Instagram account and use google dev tools and look at the cookies that have been stored. 'ds_user_id' is your user ID

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From Instagram:

> On November 17, 2015, we announced a new permissions review process
>   for new and existing apps on the [Instagram for Developers blog](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update).
>   All existing apps have until June 1, 2016 to submit for review before
>   being transitioned to sandbox mode. Please submit for review only if
>   you are in compliance with one of our approved use cases.

You need to get your API usage approved.

Check Instagram's [Platform Policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/) for use cases that are not allowed.

Comment: I you get approved, can you still access public data without having authorisation? Or is it a case that the app has to be approved to gain access to any type of data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-user-id for that.

If you would like to use it as an api, you can use `https://codeofaninja.com/tools/find-instagram-id-answer.php?instagram_username={username}` and then parse the html response to get the user id

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the access token.. there will be id in the json response

{"access_token": "", "user": {"username": "abcdef", "bio": "", "website": "", "profile_picture":", "full_name": "ABCEDEFE", **"id": "000000000"}**}

We can get userid by using this link.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN