# My Instagram client has been disabled without any precaution?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

So I've recently released my app to market. I didn't observe any rate limits because some guy said it's not needed. However from yesterday afterwards my Instagram client is not fully functioning. The response code from API endpoints is:

> "error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","code":400,"error_message":"This client has not been approved to access this resource."

When i checked my client permissions, all its permissions other than basic are pending reviewed without me doing anything! It's not a sandbox issue because it's a new client. A few months before this happened, They approved my app and my client to get some permissions so i went live after that. And i don't know what to do now? How to contact Instagram?

Comment: You need to get your API usage approved: [Instagram API -Get the userId](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37593079/2108547)

Comment: Thanks but it's not my case. I submitted my app for review months ago and after approval, i got my app to live mode out of sandbox mode.